# Trying to make Google Forms put Questions and Answers in a Google Doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a test google form that I am using for this. The goal is that someone will fill out the form and a google doc will be created with the persons answers. So far I have been able to figure out how to make the form create a doc with the answers. I can't seem to get the questions to display in the doc as well.

```
function myFunction(e) {

     var Name = e.values[1];
  var A1 = e.values[1];
  var A2 = e.values[2];
  var A3 = e.values[3];
  var A4 = e.values[4];


  var doc = DocumentApp.create( Name + 'PEL');

  var body = doc.getBody();

  body.appendParagraph(A1)
  body.appendParagraph(A2)
  body.appendParagraph(A3)
  body.appendParagraph(A4)

  doc.saveAndClose()

}
```

This is the code I'm using, It's a function that activates when ever the form is filled out. I have tried using different .get scripts to pull up the cell where the question are located but It doesn't seem to work no matter what I do.

Help please.

Comment: I think if you run your code in the form rather than the spreadsheet you can get responses and questions (not sure but I thinks so).

Comment: Cooper, running the script on the form (instead of the sheet) generates a blank doc >_>

Comment: how do you get your e? is it a onSubmit trigger?

Comment: take a look at the [Google Form Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_forms_events).

Comment: @LioraHaydont yea. the script runs on a submit trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the for data with you `event` object.

```
var questions = e.source.getItems();
var B1 = questions[0].getTitle();
var B2 = questions[1].getTitle();
//etc...
```

Comment: Liora that doesnt seem to work. From the sheet side it doesnt do anything except prevent the script from running at all

Comment: Your script worked when attached to the form directly, now i just gotta see if I can get the answers as well